# Error in grid.Call

Tags: r, ggplot2, runtime-error

while trying to generate any plot using `ggplot2`, the following error is given:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 11 could not be loaded
```

I already searched the web, any remotely related post didn't solve the issue. 
The simple example that I'm trying to plot is :

```
f = data.frame(one = c(1:5), two = c(6:10))
ggplot(f, aes(one,two)) + geom_point()
```

I updated my `ggplot2 (ggplot2_3.0.0)` yet it is still not working.

**Edit:** I'm working on ubuntu, and in the terminal, i.e. no `Rstudio`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Ubuntu 18.04 and later open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt install r-cran-plotly
   ```

   This command will install r-cran-ggplot2 version 2.2.1-3 as a dependency in Ubuntu 18.04, so if you already have ggplot2 installed then uninstall it first, and let `sudo apt install r-cran-plotly` install the package maintainers version of ggplot2.

   In earlier Ubuntu releases than Ubuntu 18.04 plotly can be installed with the following commands, but you'll have a lot more fun working with R if your Ubuntu is 18.04 or later:

   ```
   sudo R -e "install.packages('ggplot2', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
   sudo R -e "install.packages('plotly', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
   ```
2. Start R with the command `R`
3. Run the code in the original question. Type each of these commands after the command prompt and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   f = data.frame(one = c(1:5), two = c(6:10))
   ggplot(f, aes(one,two)) + geom_point()
   ```
4. Quit the R session.

   ```
   q()
   ```

   Or use the unabbreviated command `quit()` but after a couple of times you'll want to use `q()` to quit the R session instead.

The results of `ggplot(f, aes(one,two)) + geom_point()` are shown in this screenshot.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: thanks, that is is what worked at the end. Thank you all.

Comment: For me, having a specific installation of R using linuxbrew, this is not a viable option!

Comment: on arch `yay -S r-plotly r-heatmaply`

Answer (score 2):

```
> capabilities()

sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

This may caused by cairo

Comment: You have to rebuild R.  and configure R with ./configure  --enable-R-shlib --with-cairo=yes   The link https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200659217-RStudio-can-t-find-X11-fonts-on-Ubuntu-12-04-x86-64 may help.

Comment: thank you, running capabilities() showed that both cairo and X11 are true. I did as you said, restarted the machine, but I still get the same error.

Comment: The only thing that is FALSE when running capabilities(): tiff, aqua, & profmem

Comment: That's strange. I run capabilities() and showed `cairo` is FALSE and then I install `libcairo2-dev` and re-install R from source, and it is ok.   Your `cairo` seems okay, I don't know how to figure it out, sorry.

Comment: Installing libcairo2-dev and rebuilding R also fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 18.04 the problem can appear again. It was enough, in my case, to indicate the right bitmap (*i.e.* "cairo").

```
options(bitmapType="cairo")
```